# SherlockFragmentActivity setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility does not work

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i am trying to display the indeterminate progress bar in the `SherlockFragmentActivity`
but my code displays only the ActionBar without the `ProgreessBar` in it

Here is My code i am running in Android 4.1.1

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;
....
....
public class SowahActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
....
...
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_list_view);
}
...
...
}
```

what makes the progress dialog not appearing in the Actionbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to set the progress bar before the `Activity` has been created. Try reordering it like this instead:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.my_list_view);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: The request should be before the super call. The setSupport call should be after setContentView.

Comment: The reason this won't work before `setContentView` is that the action bar hasn't initialized its views yet hence there is nothing to set. You need to trigger the initialization someway before you set the visibility, even if that's only making a dummy call to `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: @JakeWharton Right, that makes sense. BTW, Jake I think you're the man. It's my dream to be a total badass coder like you someday... and ActionBarSherlock is incredible :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 //This has to be called before setContentView and you must use the
        //class in com.actionbarsherlock.view and NOT android.view
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```